# TRIGGER not inserting values in table

Tags: mysql, function, triggers

I have the following `trigger`

```
CREATE TRIGGER Insert_Orders BEFORE INSERT ON `Orders`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Payments (RestaurantPaymentInVAT, VATID) VALUES (
        (SELECT Get_RestaurantPaymentInVAT(NEW.`OrderID`)), 1);
END $$
```

However `payments.RestaurantPaymentInVAT` in the table results window doesn't show my any kind of non-null results. All of it is `null`. HOWEVER:

When I test it as a standalone query

```
SELECT Get_RestaurantPaymentInVAT(NEW.`OrderID`)
```

It gives the correct value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `Get_RestaurantPaymentInVAT` read from `Orders` table?

Comment: Yes it does, it sums the orderrows of a given orderID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `OrderID` is defined as auto-increment.  Since you're using a  `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, `OrderID` is indeed NULL, because it has not been assigned a value yet.  It will get a value AFTER it the record has been inserted.  Try changing to an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, or explicitly providing a value for `OrderID`.  That should fix it.

Comment: My line of thinking too... But can you just insert either NULL or 0 for the AI column and the next available sequence value will be inserted? Even if this is a new table and the very first insert, shouldn't it go ahead and insert?

Comment: Ah so MySQL triggers and inserts have a certain execution order list. Will test this first thing in the morning. For theorycrafting purposes only, is it possible to get the last ID# and do a +1 to it for a new insert and use that for the `NEW.\`OrderID\`` ?

Comment: @J2112O Orders.OrderID is getting populated.  The problem lies in using the value in the function call BEFORE it's populated, because it's a BEFORE INSERT trigger and the AI value is determined at INSERT time.  Create a table and define two triggers - a BEFORE and AFTER trigger that log an AI value to a different table.  The BEFORE trigger should always produce a NULL (unless you explicitly provide a value).

Comment: @KevinBott . Thanks for the detailed explanation. Makes sense.